# How can i use "MPMusicPlayerController" to playlist from my website in my Iphone app

Tags: iphone, mp3, playlist

i'm a beginning so i hope to explain me in easy way.

how can i use MPMusicPlayerController to play sound list in my iPhone app.

if i have many mp3 files in my website how can play these files automatically ?

i mean when open my app auto start 1.mp3 and when it finish 2.mp3 start automatically ?

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with `MPMusicPlayerController` as that class can only play music from the user's iPod library. From the docs:

> You use an MPMusicPlayerController object, or music player, to play media items from the iPod library.

Comment: thank you Ole,

OK is there are other way for that ? what about AVAudioPlayer ?