# How to play music on MPMusicPlayerController using array of music urls

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

How to play music using MPMUsicPlayerController using set of urls, how do I create MpMediaItemCollection using urls.

```
MPMusicPlayerController* playa;
            playa = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
            [playa setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
            [playa play];
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263962/12396017

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i use "MPMusicPlayerController" to playlist from my website in my Iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263894/how-can-i-use-mpmusicplayercontroller-to-playlist-from-my-website-in-my-iphone)